# How to hide some categories in category list under post in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

In My WordPress Blog there are some categories  use for the internal work. I want to hide that categories in blog homepage category list show under each post.

I print category list as `print(the_category($postID));`

How to hide or make filter for that category list print under each post?

Comment: Please add more detail. These "internal" categories, do you want to always hide, also hide unless ___, etc

Comment: Yah I want to hide it always.

Comment: Thanks guys; I found answer from [here](http://codegrad.hub.ph/excluding-categories-in-wordpress-post-category-list/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide the selected category on front end, try to use `get_the_terms` filters. maybe like this, try to add this to your `functions.php`

```
add_filter('get_the_terms', 'hide_categories_terms', 10, 3);
function hide_categories_terms($terms, $post_id, $taxonomy){

    // list of category slug to exclude, 
    $exclude = array('your-term-slug', 'another-term-to-hide');

    if (!is_admin()) {
        foreach($terms as $key => $term){
            if($term->taxonomy == "category"){
                if(in_array($term->slug, $exclude)) unset($terms[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $terms;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

my solution :

```
.cat-item-1 {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to grab the categories for the post, take out what ones you don't want, then display.

```
<?php
$postCats = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);
$cats =  array();

foreach($postCats as $c){
 $cats[]= get_cat_name($c);
}
$dontShow = array("List","the","Categories","here");
echo implode(", ", array_diff($cats,$dontShow);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$exclu_categories=array(
    1=>'',
    34 => '',
    45=>'',
);
$categoires=get_the_category();

foreach($categoires as $category) {

   $cat_id=$category->cat_ID;
   $cat_name=$category->name;

   if(!isset($exclu_categories[$cat_id])) {
      echo $cat_name;
   }

}
```